# Template and is_same() doesn't work?

Tags: c++, templates

```
if (std::is_same<T, float>::value)
    {
        float a;
        somefunc_float(x,len,&a);
    }
```

The above code is from a template, which accept a pointer x  that can be a pointer of some primitive data type (e.g. x being `double *`, `float *` or `int *`), and `somefunc_float` is from a lib, can only accept one specific data type of `x` (`float *` in the above example), the compiler always give me error, telling me the input data type (x) is incorrect, as if the expression`std::is_same<T, float>::value` doest work at all?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: It doesn't work the way *you* think it works. Type traits should be used in a *static* setting, i.e. in specializations and overloads.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: How about "`x` cannot be converted to type `float`"?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Are there any other ways that I can do the above job with template, thanks?

Comment: @user0002128: Yes: Specializations and overloading.

Comment: Are you referring to the variable `x` or `&a`?

Comment: @user0002128: If I understand what you want to do, then you can do multiple things, but there is not enough context in the question to point you to the best approach: overloads, specializations, SFINAE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of the problem is not completely clear, but I think I understand what you are trying to do: You are enclosing a block of code inside the template function with a test that can be performed at compile time, and expect that the compiler will discard that block and not compile it.

Templates don't work like that. When a template is instantiated, the whole template is checked and compiled and the code must be correct before the optimizer can discard blocks of code (which it probably would in this case).

The common approach to obtain that behavior is providing multiple implementations of the template (or non-template overloads) that are called with different types. The compiler will dispatch at the place of call to the appropriate implementation and will then ignore the rest.

---

There are proposals for `static if` functionality in a future version of C++ (probably C++17) that would support what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I know the overload/multiple template ways, I want to save a bit of time, but it seems that it never work, thanks for clarify things anyway.

Comment: @user0002128: Depending on what you want to do, you could just factor that condition into a function, and provide an overload for `float` and a templated version that is a no-op. Whether that is a sensible design or not, depends on a lot of information that is not present in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Now that we have C++17, your approach became valid. However, a minor yet crucial correction is needed:

```cpp
// is_same_v is an alias for is_same<...>::value
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) {  
    float a;
    somefunc_float(x,len,&a);
}
```

`if constexpr` is a compile-time evaluated variant of the regular if statement, similar in a way to the preprocessor `#if`. See the [documentation of if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Types are determined *statically*, and all template code that is instantiated must compile, i.e. make sense. The content of an `if` statement must make sense even if the condition is false.

Try something like this:

```
template <typename T> execute_if_float(T) { }

execute_if_float(float x) { somefunc_float(x); }


template <typename T> void myCode(T x)
{
    // ...

    execute_if_float(x);

    // ...
}
```